# how to Compare two fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to **compare two fields in Elasticsearch**. I tried with below query using Kibana. But it's a gave runtime exception. Kindly help me how to compare these fields.

```
GET /eps/_search
  {
      "query": {
          "bool" : {
              "filter" : {
                  "script" : {
                      "script" : {
                          "source": "doc['output_record_count'].value <  doc['input_record_count'].value",
                          "lang"   : "painless"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Note:
For complete Match query I am getting below success response.
Query:

```
GET /eps/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

The Response is :

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "eps",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9bNkeXEBLNJ-eURYKdv1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "experience" : "EPS",
          "@version" : "1",
          "sdcids" : "013bb234-0840-11ea-8e7d-515f88cf3efa",
          "output_record_count" : 13,
          "input_record_count" : 10,
          "@timestamp" : "2020-04-14T15:52:19.582Z",
          "SDC_Ids" : "013bb234-0840-11ea-8e7d-515f88cf3efa"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact exception? What's your mapping?

Comment: I achieve this with below query                                                                                           {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "source" : "doc['field1'].value < doc['field2'].value",
            "lang" : "painless"
          },
          "boost" : 1.0
        }                                                                                                                                         But I need to add ternary operation for doc['field1'].value.  Example: if(doc['field1'].value == NULL ? 0 : doc['field1'].value).  Pls suggest